# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement + 7 more errors

Tags: c#

I've found a lot of good answers and help here for my project but now im getting kinda confused with my code i get 8 errors on my code

```
private bool HasBeta(int id) => 
    (MenuClients[id][5].ToString() == "True");
```

The errors i now get are as following

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

---

> Method must have a return type

---

> Invalid token '5' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

---

> Invalid token '[' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

---

> Identifier expected

---

> ; expected

---

> 'MainWindow.HasBeta(int)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: Please show a wider scope. Where does this code fit into

Comment: I am not sure what you are tryin to do here but certainley there is no such syntax in c#. Are you trying to declare a delegate and initialize it with a lambda at the same time?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using here?

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis This is valid C# syntax

Comment: Im using VS2013, this should be for the Main windowframe so if someone has beta or not, all code works beside this one now

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis This is valid C#. It was added in C# 6 as a shortcut feature for declaring single-line methods and getter properties, and C# 7 expanded the feature by allowing the syntax on constructors, finalizers, and property accessors as well.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2013, you will be using C# version 5. The code you have is only valid in C# version 6 and above. Expression Bodied Functions and Properties were introduced in version 6 in July 2015 - see [this list of features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn802602.aspx).

I'm not aware of a simple way to use version 6 of C# in VS2013 so my advice is to upgrade, preferably to VS2017.

Comment: Oh thanks, so i would need VS2015 right? :)

Comment: I did hear of someone managing to get it working in VS2013, but it was a nasty hack and pretty sure it's not supported.

Comment: @AndyB VS2015 would get you C# 6, but the recommendation is to use VS2017 as it would get you C# 7 as well as the most up to date updates and features. Unless you have a specific reason to stay back with 2013/2015, there's no reason not to upgrade to 2017.

Comment: @AndyB Did this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, i now installed VS17 and it works great! thank you a lot!

Comment: @AndyB Great, don't forget you can accept answer that help you :)